# MultiPatch Shapefile import into PostGIS Database

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, multipatch

I have geometry of buildings in Shapefile MultiPatch format. I want to import it into PostGIS database in the same format.

Is that even possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include the software you would use for the conversion.

Comment: According to the [ogr2ogr docs](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html), "MultiPatch files are read and each patch geometry is turned into a multi-polygon representation with one polygon per triangle in triangle fans and meshes." So, not exactly the same format.

Comment: When I tried to import it with tool pgShapeLoader, it appeared as "unsupported data type". Can you help me how can I get this data to DB, please? Thanks for answer.

Comment: This is possible using FME Shapefile to PostGIS. I have achieved it before and it creates Tin Zs and PolyhedralSurfaces

Comment: @JohnPowell From that description in docs I would expect that all the resulting polygons are triangles so they all have exactly 3 vertices, but I'm getting polygons with variable number of vertices. It doesn't make sense to me..

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite old but just came across the same issue and wanted to share a solution. Strictly speaking John Powell is right – it can't be the same format because it needs to be converted on import to a [PostGIS-supported form](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT). However, using `ogr2ogr` you have some control over how this happens:

Something like `$ ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=localhost port=5432 user=your_name dbname=db password=pass" "path_to_multipatch.gdb" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=no -nln table_name -overwrite` will create a PostGIS table with the default MULTIPOLYGON Z geometry type.

By adding `-nlt "POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z"` you can choose to import as polyhedral surfaces instead, which may be better depending on the use case. I believe this will also work if you want TIN Z, as with James Milner's solution using FME Shapefile to PostGIS.